# Atualizar dados usando LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Li que LINQ deve ser usado para consultas, porém, no contexto abaixo, a melhor maneira que encontrei para atualizar foi usando o `let`.

```
var produtos = from o in orcItens    
    join p in Produtos on o.Id equals p.Id   
    let x = p.Estoque -= o.Quantidade
    select p;
```

- `Produtos` é uma classe `IQueryable<>` que será persistida.
- `orcItens` é uma lista de `ids`, `quantidade` dos produtos vendidos

Existe outra maneira de atualizar os dados, utilizando *lambda*, por exemplo?

Tentei usar `foreach` porém não consegui pegar os dados agrupados.

Comment: É possível fazer muita coisa com o linq, um exemplo bem perto do que você quer pode ser visto aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/14139472/3517631, dentro do loop pode desenvolver a ideia, mas tenta dar uma ideia melhor da dúvida, aí ficaria mais fácil formular uma boa resposta

Comment: Realmente a ideia é utilizar o `ForEach` mostrado na resposta indicada, porém, minha consulta traz dados agrupados, `Produtos`, `orcItens`, ao utilizar `ForEach` ex: `produtos.ForEach` não consigo acessar os dados do orçamento, no meu exemplo seria `o.Quantidade`.

Comment: É porque você está fazendo `select p` onde `p` é produto, então a consulta não acessa orçamento. Não sei o todo do sistema, mas eu sugiro a criação de uma outra classe para fazer o tratamento de negocio em cima desses objetos. Aí no `select` vc pode retornar um `new MEUOBJETO` e assim ter os dados como quiser.

Comment: Entedi, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O LINQ é uma linguagem para fazer consultas apenas, ele "não permite" que você faça alterações em coleções de dados.

Então para resolver o seu problema o ideal seria fazer uma consulta pelos "produtos" que correspondem aos "orçamentos", colocar esse resultado em um objeto e no final da consulta juntar todos esses objetos em uma coleção. Em seguida utilizaria um `foreach` nessa coleção para atualizar os dados.

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fazer isso. Supondo que você tenha as classes abaixo:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Estoque { get; set; }
}

public class Orcamento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
}
```

Defina uma classe para fazer a associação entre o "produto" e o "orçamento" correspondente:

```
public class ProdutoOrcamento
{
    public Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public Orcamento Orcamento { get; set; }
}
```

Faça a consulta, armazene o resultado, e através de um `foreach` atualize os dados na instância de Produto:

```
var produtosOrcamentos = (from o in orcamentos
                          join p in produtos on o.Id equals p.Id
                          select new ProdutoOrcamento { Produto = p, Orcamento = o });

foreach (var i in produtosOrcamentos)
{
    i.Produto.Estoque = i.Orcamento.Quantidade;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ -> Language-integrated QUERY

Query -> Consulta

Até é possível, mas LINQ foi criado para fazer consultas. Não tente subverter sua função, principalmente sem dominar profundamente seu funcionamento e as consequências de fazer isto.

Vá de `foreach` (comando) e seja feliz. Obviamente pode usar o LINQ para selecionar o que vai atualizar.

Cuidado para não complicar o *design* da aplicação só para facilitar o uso do LINQ. Faça o melhor para o modelo, se o LINQ não se encaixar nele, azar do LINQ.